# ADO Wiki - Possible to create separate branches or repositories for different audiences?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

My question is if it is possible to create separate branches when utilizing "publish code as wiki" option and make some of them private? Meaning that if I went to the wiki page section, only a "group" of people can see and edit this part (branch) of the code wiki. If so, how would I do this and set the proper branch policies?

I'm trying to do this so that my internal team can document things only for our team and have another one that is public to everyone else.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do like as below:

1. Create a branch (e.g., **`Wiki`**) and only put the Wiki markdown files (**`.md`**) into this branch.

   [image]
2. Create a group/team (e.g., **`Wiki Editors`** group) and add all the users who need to access the Wiki pages into this group/team.

   [image]
3. On the security hub of the **`Wiki`** branch, give the **`Wiki Editors`** group the '**`Contribute`**' permission at least. And try to set all permissions as **`Deny`** as possible for other users and groups/teams on this branch.

   [image]
4. When you "**`Publish code as wiki`**", select the **`Wiki`** branch.

   [image]

**Note:** This method can let only the **`Wiki Editors`** group be able to edit the files on the **`Wiki`** branch, but it cannot avoid other users and groups/teams to see/view the files on the **`Wiki`** branch. Because there is no option to deny particular users and groups/teams to see/view branch.

---